# Validation accuracy has only a few values in big dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, parameters, deep-learning, tensorboard

I am trying to train a modified verison of google inception V3 with a dataset of 50 000 samples of shape (?, 5, 150, 200, 1) - 5 time distributed frames of 150x200 grayscale pictures. Strangely enough, when I tried the vanilla inceptionV3 ( without time distribution ) I had around 60% accuracy, working with the batch size being 100 frames ( i mean, the batchsize parameter ). When I use time distribution,  i cannot fit more than one (5, 150, 200, 1) pack into memory. Anyway, the model doesn't seem to imporve in accuracy ( currently at 50k steps ), but strangely enough, the v_accuracy only takes 2 values so far: 0.14 and 0.12.

I have to mention that the data is well formatted ( i visualized it, and tested it in the other model ).

So the question is.. Is it normal for the validation accuracy to look like this?

I also tried to change the LR to 0.001, 0.0001, 0.0005.
Does anyone know what the problem is?

Thanks in advance! [image]

[image]

Comment: What *exactly* is your *question*?

Comment: Is it normal to have my validation accuracy like that? ( only .14 and .12 ). And what could be the cause? The data is split in 20000 training samples and 5000 validation samples

Comment: Pls donot the comments space for this - **edit & update** your question instead